# Eclipse's not Run As does not show Java Application

Tags: java, eclipse

I am using Eclipse IDE for Java Developers - 2021-12. The code I am working on here works fine on every other code editor, but I cannot run it on this one. I had tried other ways to fix this but it has not worked so far.
[image of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jQrtq.png)
[the ant debug error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yv3vq.png)

```
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.ZoneId;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.time.ZoneId;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class Main {
  public static String GetTime(){
    ZoneId zoneid = ZoneId.of("Asia/Ho_Chi_Minh");

    DateTimeFormatter format = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy; HH:mm:ss");
    LocalDateTime localtime = LocalDateTime.now(zoneid);
    String time = localtime.format(format);
    return time;
  }
  public static void WindowOpen(){
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Time");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    JLabel label = new JLabel(GetTime(),SwingConstants.CENTER);
    label.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300,100));
    frame.getContentPane().add(label,BorderLayout.CENTER);
    frame.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.decode("#f88379"));
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);

    Timer timer = new Timer(1000,new ActionListener(){
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent a){
        label.setText(GetTime());
      }
    }
    );
    timer.start();
  }
  public static void main(String[] args){
    WindowOpen();
  }
}
```

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Comment: I can't find any errors that the Eclipse code editor gave me except if I go to debug and run it with Ant, it says that it cannot run it.

Comment: If it 'says' that it 'cannot run it', then paste the exact error in your question. Your code isn't the problem, your setup is. Your question boils down to: "I tried this thing that works for many people but it doesn't work for me." - and left it at that.

Comment: My guess is that, at some point, you had another "Main" class in your _Run Configurations_ list and that compiled class is still sitting in your _bin_ or _target_ folder. What you need to do is to clean your project and force all classes to recompile. While you are at it, clear the _Run Configurations_ list. Please let me know if this fixed your issue.

Answer (score 1):

You source file is not under a **Java Project**'s **Source Folder**, it's on your Desktop. You can't arbitrarily run `.java` source files in Eclipse--there's no place from which to construct the correct runtime classpath, including which JRE.

Create a **Java Project** using the wizard and put your source file into the **Source Folder** that's created for you. Then you will be able to run it.